# save changes in table with ajax created field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm setting up an ajaxy form in which an administrator should be able to click an add button ( + ) to add a new entry into a mysql table and make that input editable. The add button works to add a new line but the new line is 'dead'.  Adding data to the input fileds does not call the ajax php file to save the data which includes the function to remove ( - ) the line.

The HTML in both the form and dynamically added div:

```
<div class="form-group" >
  <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Friend's name</label>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control saveFname" name="fname" id="34"  gid="99" value="" placeholder="First name" /></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control saveLname" name="lname" id="34" gid="99"  value="" placeholder="Last name" /></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton" id="34" gid="99" ><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></div>
</div>
```

The javascript to add a field group:

```
// ADD GROUP BUTTON
.on('click', '.addButton', function() {
  var ID=$(this).attr('id');
  var GID=$(this).attr('gid');
  var LAST=$(this).attr('last');
  $("#showGroup").html( "" );
  var dataString = 'name=add' +'&id='+ID +'&gid='+GID +'&last='+LAST;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addGroup2.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
      $("#showGroup").html( html );
    }
  })
})
// END ADD GROUP BUTTON
```

The javascript save fieldgroup data:

```
// SAVE FNAME
$('.saveFname').keyup(function()
{
  var check=$(this).val();
  var avail=remove_whitespaces(check);
  var ID=$(this).attr('id');
  var GID=$(this).attr('gid');
  $("#Results").html( "" );
  if(avail!=''){
    $('.check_saveFname').show();
    var String = 'fname='+ avail;
    var dataString = 'fname='+ avail +'&id='+ID;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "saveGroup2.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
      {
        $("#Results").html( html );
      }
    });
  }else{
    $('.check_saveFname').html('');
  }
});
// END SAVE FNAME
```

How do you go about making the dynamically added input respond to the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using event delegation for `.addButton` and you should do the same with your `.saveFname` input field:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.saveFname', function(){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I did this and it works perfectly.  I also tried the other options posted by the other commenter but only this works.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line

```
$('.saveFname').keyup(function()
...
```

to

```
$('.saveFname').live('keyup',function()
...
```

or

```
$('.saveFname').bind('keyup',function()
...
```

or

```
$(document).on('keyup','.saveFname',function()
...
```

Hope this helps you out. Let me know in case you still face any issue.